# rake error with ActiveRecord in Ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rake

I'm following a tutorial with Sinatra + Ruby with Active Record + Postgresql and the error I always end up with when doing any task or even just running the `rake` command is:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `root=' for ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks:Module
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.2/lib/sinatra/activerecord/rake/activerecord_4.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.2/lib/sinatra/activerecord/rake/activerecord_4.rb:8:in `tap'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.2/lib/sinatra/activerecord/rake/activerecord_4.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.2/lib/sinatra/activerecord/rake.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/user/Documents/dev_testbed/debug/sinatra2/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Unfortunately can't find anything related to this error on the internet.

using:

```
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
rake 10.3.2
```

Comment: The error has got something to do with the "postgresql" adapter defined in the database.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I either didn't have activerecord gem installed or was using an old version.
Simply running `gem install activerecord` solved the issue.